# EKS: Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: Multiple tagged security groups found for instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, kubectl, amazon-eks

```
Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  54s (x4 over 91s)  service-controller  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: Multiple tagged security groups found for instance i-05f3a11329a20bb93; ensure only the k8s security group is tagged; the tagged groups were sg-08ca90265d3402e6c(education-eks-ooHfNJwm-node-20221205083117267100000007) sg-04ad04b5d3bb35e66(eks-cluster-sg-education-eks-ooHfNJwm-1857011925)
  Normal   EnsuringLoadBalancer    14s (x5 over 94s)  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Warning  SyncLoadBalancerFailed  13s                service-controller  Error syncing load balancer: failed to ensure load balancer: Multiple tagged security groups found for instance i-046c2cc46714af250; ensure only the k8s security group is tagged; the tagged groups were sg-08ca90265d3402e6c(education-eks-ooHfNJwm-node-20221205083117267100000007) sg-04ad04b5d3bb35e66(eks-cluster-sg-education-eks-ooHfNJwm-1857011925)
```

I created the cluster with this code: [eks using terraform](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/kubernetes/eks)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add in eks module will fix issue.

```
node_security_group_tags = {
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}" = null
  }
```

### Ref:

https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1986
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/1810

Comment: Thanks, works for me.
I have used the same tutorial from description+ deploy Knative into EKS